# Left and right arrow keys are not working?

Tags: keyboard

I have some issues with my keyboard left and right arrow keys are not working. How do i fix that. Other keys are working as well as the top and bottom arrow keys.

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem that is unrelated to Ubuntu. Have you tried using your keyboard on other computers?

Comment: Well I'm using a laptop in fact. Is Asus U36SD soo ... idk where else to test this keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Buy or borrow a wireless USB keyboard to see if it's your laptop's keyboard (buy a new one for 25 bucks) or a software problem. There are lots of nice Microsoft and Logitech wireless USB keyboards you might like to buy and keep using, otherwise I'm sure a friend has one you can borrow for an evening.